# Dynamics CRM 2015 - update Opportunity Owner id via javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm trying to update the OwnerId on an opportunity in Dynamics CRM 2015.

So far I am using the following code but my changes are not taking effect.

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('ownerid').setValue('487ecd0c-d8c1-e411-80eb-c4346bade4b0')
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

This is a view of the GetValue call.

[image]

The attribute type is "lookup" and when I call getIsDirty(), it returns false after I do setValue, so I'm not sure if that's the correct way to set the value on a "lookup" type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Owner` is a special field, it can be changed only with an `AssignRequest`.

With CRM Online Update 1 this changed, special fields like `Owner` or `StateCode` can be updated with an update request, but as far as I know this is valid from server side, for client side changes you will still need to use an `AssignRequest`.

Here a sample code:

[Using Assign Requests to Assign Entities to a User Using Jscript and .NET in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-use-assign-requests-to-assign.html)

EDIT:
Just for reference, this is the way to set a lookup field

```
var lookup = new Array();
lookup[0] = new Object();
lookup[0].id = '{487ecd0c-d8c1-e411-80eb-c4346bade4b0}';
lookup[0].name = 'Test Account';
lookup[0].entityType = 'account';
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_account").setValue(lookup);
```

or short version

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_account").setValue([{ id: '{487ecd0c-d8c1-e411-80eb-c4346bade4b0}', name: 'Test Account', entityType: 'account'}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to set entityType to "systemuser" but the javascript code you posted worked perfect for me.

Comment: just a curiosity, can you post the exact CRM version you are working on? 7.X.X?

Comment: "7.0.1.247 DB 7.0.1.237"  It says CRM Online 2015 Update,  I don't see a 1 though

Comment: Thanks, I will need to check this behavior with different CRM versions, however good that the JS I posted worked for you

Comment: @TWilly sorry if I bother you with another question, this script to change the owner, runs when the record is not yet created or for existing records?

Comment: Right now I'm using it only for existing records.  I haven't tried it with creating a new record but I'd assume it would work.